# Using composer.json in Symfony 2.0

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.0

I have a Symfony 2.0 project; however, I'd like to switch from `deps` to `composer.json` without going up to 2.1+. Has anyone done this, or is there anything that would prevent this from working?

Comment: Support for Symfony 2.0 [has already stopped](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html). Are you sure you don't want to upgrade?

Comment: @Touki personally I would but it's not a feasible for the project atm

Comment: Had a project where we were in exactly the same situation. We upgraded to composer within one day. Was not a big deal though it was a big project.

Comment: Specify the correct version in composer. I assume that makes it not break anything. Still do testing in development and staging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a page that shows you how to switch to composer for Symfony 2.0:
http://knplabs.com/fr/blog/symfony2-with-composer

Comment: The link is broken.